# Epicycles as a Fourier series. Geocentric solar system model

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy, fourier-transform

I'm trying to plot planets' trajectories as seen from stationary Earth perspective.

I tried to look for some data online, but I wasn't able to find anything but some old manuscripts. 
[image]

I was thinking about the following approach:

1. represent the eliptical orbits around the sun as a Fourier series (n.b. harmonic representation of closed curves)
2. change the reference frame to one in which Earth is stationary.

I'm wondering if anybody has a better way of doing this or if there exists already some data online.

I"m interested in a parametrised form for each planet (p):
$$x_{p}(t)=...\\
y_{p}(t)=...$$
where the RHS is given by a Fourier Series. I think it should be also possible to write $z_{p}(t)=x_{p}(t)+i y_{p}(t)$ with $i=\sqrt{-1}$ which would be even more desirable.

Comment: Note that epicycle expansion is not the same as Fourier series: in the latter all frequencies are multiples of the fundamental, while in the former the frequencies are independent of each other. This in particular allows to approximate non-periodic functions.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, it's worth to keep that in mind

Comment: Not sure, but [this amazing answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/72479/448779) may be interesting.